# How to execute this code in a .JAR file however in IDE works

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, windows-10, javafx-8

When I execute this code in my Ide IntelliJ, it works perfect. But when I do it in my file .JAR finally, it does not work.

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun extractZipMachineFromJar(file: String?, destination: String?) {
    var `in`: ZipInputStream? = null
    var out: OutputStream? = null
    try { // Open the ZIP file
        `in` = ZipInputStream((URL(file)).openStream())
        // Get the first entry
        var entry: ZipEntry? = null
        while (`in`.nextEntry.also { entry = it } != null) {
            val outFilename = entry!!.name
            // Open the output file
            if (entry!!.isDirectory) {
                File(destination, outFilename).mkdirs()
            } else {
                out = FileOutputStream(File(destination, outFilename))
                // Transfer bytes from the ZIP file to the output file
                val buf = ByteArray(1024)
                var len: Int
                while (`in`.read(buf).also { len = it } > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len)
                }
                out.close()
            }
        }
    } finally { // Close the stream
        `in`?.close()
        if (out != null) {
            out.close()
        }
    }
}
```

And in the button that i click

```
val file = File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\main\\kotlin\\extractFolder\\myFiles.zip").path.toString()
extractZipMachineFromJar(file, folderWhereIExtractTo)
```

I suspect this is how I manage to access my resource inside the .Jar file. But I have no idea because when I execute it from my IDE it works.

Does anyone know how this code example works in a .JAR file?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.5 Community Edition,
Kotlin 1.3.70,
Java 1.8.0_271,
Java Fx 8.0.241,
TornadoFX 1.7.20,
Windows 10 19041.746

Thanks

**Update:**

I tried this solution but I think I am wrong applying correct code.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MainView::class.java.get…/myFiles.zip") must not be null

This is my modified code and screenshot of my project, folders and files.

[image]

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun extractZipMachineFromJar(url : URL, destination: String?) {
    var `in`: ZipInputStream? = null
    var out: OutputStream? = null
    try { // Open the ZIP file
        `in` = ZipInputStream(MainView::class.java.getResourceAsStream(url.toString()))
        // Get the first entry
        var entry: ZipEntry? = null
        while (`in`.nextEntry.also { entry = it } != null) {
            val outFilename = entry!!.name
            // Open the output file
            if (entry!!.isDirectory) {
                File(destination, outFilename).mkdirs()
            } else {
                out = FileOutputStream(File(destination, outFilename))
                // Transfer bytes from the ZIP file to the output file
                val buf = ByteArray(1024)
                var len: Int
                while (`in`.read(buf).also { len = it } > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len)
                }
                out.close()
            }
        }
    } finally { // Close the stream
        `in`?.close()
        if (out != null) {
            out.close()
        }
    }
}
```

```
val url : URL = MainView::class.java.getResource("/folderWithZip/myFiles.zip")
extractZipMachineFromJar(url, rutaCarpetasDLLMasBinDentro)
```

And this is my MainApp.kt

```
fun main() {
    launch<MainApp>()
}

class MainApp : App(MainView::class) { // me inyecta una clase

    override fun start(stage: Stage) {
        stage.minHeight = pantallaProgramaAlto
        stage.minWidth = pantallaProgramaAncho
        stage.resizableProperty().set(true)
        super.start(stage)
}
```

And MainView class

```
class MainView : View(versionBarra) {
    override val root = tabpane() {
        tab<TabView>()
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.70'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.2.0'
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation "no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.20"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.4.0"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

//Definir clase principal para jar.
def mainClassName = 'playlistoPaquetorro.MainAppKt'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': mainClassName
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `current-working-dir/src/main/kotlin/blabla` obviously isn't guaranteed to exist. current-working-dir isn't guaranteed to be anything useful, this code is broken.

Resources that are as much part of your app as your compiled class files are, should be loaded using `MyClass.class.getResource("relative-path.txt")`. This will load files from the exact same place the JVM will load class files. Specifically, that instruction will look at the 'directory' where the JVM found `MyClass.class` (the class file with the bytecode representing the MyClass class, which could be on disk, or within a jar file, or within a jmod, or in a database, or generated on the fly - the classloading system is quite abstract!) - and look there for the file `relative-path.txt`. Even if it is inside that database, within a jar file, jmod file, etcetera.

Start your 'relative path' with a slash and it looks relative to the classpath root instead (so, if you have a jarfile with `/com/foo/yourapp/Main.class` and `/img/open.png`, `Main.class.getResource("/img/open.png")` is what you want.

`.getResource` gives you a URL object, which can be passed e.g. to swing JLabels and the like. `.getResourceAsStream` gives you an inputstream (make sure to call that within a try-with-resources construct!).

`File` is a non-starter. File can only represent actual files (hence the name), and java apps are not usually shipped as 'a bunch of files'. They are shipped as 'a jar file, or a bunch of jar files'. The stuff inside are entries in a jar file, and not files. `java.io.File`  cannot represent them.

--EDIT--

after the question was updated:

- The point of `src/main/kotlin` is, as the name says, that this is where your kotlin files go. a zip is not a kotlin file. Put those in `src/main/resources`.
- url.toString()? I have no idea what you're trying to do with all this complication. Just start with a hardcoded string first instead of this complicated mess. Once you figure out how it works, feel free to abstract away.
- 

Comment: I tried your solution but I think I am wrong applying correct code.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MainView::class.java.get…/myFiles.zip") must not be null

This is my modified code and screenshot of my project, folders and files.

Comment: Then you either messed up the string argument (`.getResourceAsStream` returns `null` if you name a resource that does not exist, which then causes the error you see), or your build is broken and isn't copying resources to the right place. You haven't given enough details about either what you've changed the code to now, or how your build works (how did you obtain that jar file?) to give more detail about what is wrong.

Comment: i have updated my question with more info. Now you can see my project folders and build.gradle too. Whatever you need, please tell me.Thanks.